# Python time library: how do I preserve dst with strptime and strftime

Tags: python, time, timezone, utc, dst

I need to store a timestamp in a readable format, and then later on I need to convert it to epoch for comparison purposes.

I tried doing this:

```
import time
format = '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S +0000'
timestamp1 = time.strftime(format,time.gmtime())  # '2016 03 25 04:06:22 +0000'
t1 = time.strptime(timestamp1, format) # time.struct_time(..., tm_isdst=-1)
time.sleep(1)
epoch_now = time.mktime(time.gmtime())
epoch_t1 = time.mktime(t1)
print "Delta: %s" % (epoch_now - epoch_t1)
```

Running this, instead of getting Delta of 1 sec, I get 3601 (1 hr 1 sec), CONSISTENTLY.

Investigating further, it seems that when I just do time.gmtime(), the struct has tm_isdst=0, whereas the converted struct t1 from timestamp1 string has tm_isdst=-1.

How can I ensure the isdst is preserved to 0. I think that's probably the issue here.

Or is there a better way to record time in human readable format (UTC), and yet be able to convert back to epoch properly for time diff calculation?

UPDATES:
After doing more research last night, I switched to using datetime because it preserves more information in the datetime object, and this is confirmed by albertoql answer below.

Here's what I have now:

```
from datetime import datetime
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f +0000' # +0000 is optional; only for user to see it's UTC
d1 = datetime.utcnow()
timestamp1 = d1.strftime(format)
d1a = datetime.strptime(timestamp1, format)
time.sleep(1)
d2 = datetime.utcnow()
print "Delta: %s" % (d2 - d1a).seconds
```

I chose not to add tz to keep it simple/shorter; I can still strptime that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below, first an explanation about the problem, then two possible solutions, one using [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html), another using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

## Problem explanation

The problem is on the observation that the OP made in the question: `tm_isdst=-1`. `tm_isdst` is a flag that determines whether daylight savings time is in effect or not (see for more details https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time).
Specifically, given the format of the string for the time from the OP (that complies with [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.html) Internet email standard), `[time.strptime`][4](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) does not store the information about the timezone, namely `+0000`. Thus, when the [`struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) is created again according to the information in the string, `tm_isdst=-1`, namely unknown. The guess on how to fill in that information when making the calculation is based on the local system. For example, as if the system refers to North America, where daylight savings time is in effect, `tm_isdst` is set.

## Solution with `time`

If you want to use only [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) package, then, the easiest way to parse directly the information is to specify that the time is in UTC, and thus adding `%Z` to the format. Note that `time` does not provide a way to store the information about the timezone in `struct_time`. As a result, it does not print the actual time zone associated with the time saved in the variable. The time zone is retrieved from the system. Therefore, it is not possible to directly use the same format for [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime). The part of the code for writing and reading the string would look like:

```
format = '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S UTC'
format2 = '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S %Z'
timestamp1 = time.strftime(format, time.gmtime())
t1 = time.strptime(timestamp1, format2)
```

## Solution with `datetime`

Another solution involves the use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) packages, which directly support timezone, and the code could be (assuming that  preserving the timezone information is a requirement):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz, parser
import time

time_format = '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S %z'
utc_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')

utc_time1 = datetime.utcnow()
utc_time1 = utc_time1.replace(tzinfo=utc_zone)
utc_time1_string = utc_time1.strftime(time_format)
utc_time1 = parser.parse(utc_time1_string)
time.sleep(1)
utc_time2 = datetime.utcnow()
utc_time2 = utc_time2.replace(tzinfo=utc_zone)

print "Delta: %s" % (utc_time2 - utc_time1).total_seconds()
```

There are some aspects to pay attention to:

- After the call of [`utcnow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow), the timezone is not set, as it is a naive UTC datetime. If the information about UTC is not needed, it is possible to delete both lines where the timezone is set for the two times, and the result would be the same, as there is no guess about DST.
- It is not possible to use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) because of `%z`, which is not correctly parsed. If the string contains the information about the timezone, then `parser` should be used.
- It is possible to directly perform the difference from two instances of `datetime` and transform the resulting delta into seconds.
- If it is necessary to get the time in seconds since the epoch, an explicit computation should be made, as there is no direct function that does that automatically in `datetime` (at the time of the answer). Below the code, for example for `utc_time2`:

  ```
   epoch_time = datetime(1970,1,1)
   epoch2 = (utc_time2 - epoch_time).total_seconds()
  ```
- [`datetime.resolution`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.resolution), namely the smallest possible difference between two non-equal `datetime` objects. This results in a difference that is up to the resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This all makes sense now and I am starting to think using datetime is better/more uniform than time.

Comment: > Note that time does not provide a way to store the information about the timezone in struct_time.
That's untrue as per the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time